# Is it possible to force NHibernate's stateless session to re-use a connection?

Tags: nhibernate, connection-pooling

When not using transactions, it looks like NHibernate's stateless session forces the connection to be closed after each statement (read or write).

Looking at the code, it comes out that this is happening because the ConnectionManager's `ConnectionReleaseMode` is automatically set to `AfterTransaction`, and not using transactions is interpreted as executing each statement in its own transaction.

Is there a way to change this behavior and allow a single connection to be reused for the entire lifetime of the session?

I'm using the SqlClientDriver, in case it matters.

Comment: Of course I can call `OpenStatelessSession()` passing my own connection, but then I'll have to tie myself the connection lifetime to the session lifetime...

Comment: What is your **actual** issue? (the one you're trying to solve via connection reuse)

Comment: My main issue is performance - I'm executing about 15 statements during the lifetime of a session, and I'm using ApplicationRoles, so each connection establishment requires calling the sp_setapprole stored proc. With the current behavior, the connection gets opened and closed 15 times - and the approle sp is executed 15 times - during the lifetime of a session.

Comment: What type of application is this? What is the lifetime of your session?

Comment: It's a SOA server wrapping a database and exposing the data to the company through remote API. The lifetime of a session is a single API call, but due to the complexity of the object model, a single API call can result in lots of queries being made, either SELECT's or INSERT's. And these queries can't be modeled in NHibernate as simple OM relations.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap everything in a NHibernate transaction (which is probably desirable anyway).

While the transaction is open, the connection will be open too.

Comment: I thought that, but it smells of overkillness in those cases (which are the majority in my situation) in which the set of queries are all read-only (i.e. just SELECT's)...or may be I'm just being overly sensitive :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change this behavior and allow a single connection
>   to be reused for the entire lifetime of the session?

Yes there is. Use "[hibernate.connection.release_mode](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-connection-release)" "on_close" so the connection is closed only at the close of the NHibernate session.

IMPORTANT: This option is interesting only if you are using approaches such as "session-per-request" or ["session-per-conversation"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10273922/1350308) because in these scenarios can occur a large numbers of "lazyloads" outside the transaction boundaries. See: "... *[This setting is left for backwards compatibility, but excellant use is highly discouraged](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-connection-release)* ..."

Comment: The connection release mode seems to be completely ignored by a stateless session - I'm afraid it's only enforced by the standard (stateful) session.